# Qt QWidget::minimumSizeHint delay

Tags: c++, qt, c++11

I want to write dialog with "spoiler". When I show/hide some elements, the form must resize to match her content. But I noticed that minimumSizeHint works with some delay. For example I wrote following dialog code:

dialog.h

```
#ifndef DIALOG_H
#define DIALOG_H

#include <QDialog>

class Dialog : public QDialog {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Dialog(QWidget *parent = 0);

private:
    QPushButton *button1, *button2, *button3;
    void adjust();
};

#endif // DIALOG_H
```

dialog.cpp

```
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QTimer>

#include "dialog.h"

Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent) {
    QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout;
    button1 = new QPushButton("bad method", this);
    button2 = new QPushButton("working method", this);
    button3 = new QPushButton("indent", this);
    layout->addWidget(button1);
    layout->addWidget(button2);
    layout->addWidget(button3);
    setLayout(layout);

    connect(button1, &QPushButton::pressed, [=]() {
        button3->setVisible(!button3->isVisible());

        adjust();
    });

    connect(button2, &QPushButton::pressed, [=]() {
        button3->setVisible(!button3->isVisible());

        QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
        connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, [=](){ adjust(); });
        timer->setSingleShot(true);
        timer->start(0);
    });
}

void Dialog::adjust() {
    resize(width(), minimumSizeHint().height());
}
```

When pressed button1, the form isn't match her content tightly, but when pressed button2, the form tightly match her content.
How to achieve results as pressing button2 without timers and other workarounds? Why button1 isn't work?

Comment: You have memory leak with timers. Each time you press `button2` you create `QTimer` object. And all timers are staying in memory, until you destroy your dialog. It can be fixed in next way: `QTimer::singleShot( 0, this, &Dialog::adjust );`. `adjust` must be a slot. I don't understand your overhead with lambdas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider that the minimum size is not computed until some events are processed in the event loop. If you don't want to use a timer, one workaround is to process the event loop for some iterations after the button is hidden or made visible, and then adjust size.

It's like :

```
        button3->setVisible(!button3->isVisible());

        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
           qApp->processEvents();

        adjust();
```

A better solution is to call `QLayout::activate()` before resizing:

```
        button3->setVisible(!button3->isVisible());

        layout->activate();

        adjust();
```

`activate()` forces your layout to recalculate the size hint.

Comment: This is another workaround and it isn't normal solution. Can we consider this problem as Qt bug?

Comment: It's a normal behavior in Qt and is not a bug. I would recommend to use the timer approach. I just mentioned this way because you wanted another workaround.

Comment: Why this behavior isn't specified in Qt doc? Why do you consider this as a normal behavior?

Comment: All Qt GUI related stuff are done in the main event loop. When you change items in a layout, they are updated when control returns to event loop. So i think it's normal. There is one other solution though. Call `layout->activate();` before adjusting size.

Comment: layout->activate() looks much better than the timer! I think, this is good solution. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I tried the `QLayout::activate()` solution, but it doesn't work for me.

`QLayout::activate()` returns `false`.

This is my code: `this` is a `QMainWindow`.

```
ui.groupBox->setVisible(!ui.groupBox->isVisible());

qDebug() << this->layout()->activate();

qDebug() << this->minimumSizeHint();

this->resize(this->minimumSizeHint());
```

any ideas why it's not working?

My current workaround is:

```
QTimer::singleShot(10, this, SLOT(on_resizeMin()));
```

but i noticed 10ms may not be enough on a slow system. Nasty workaround.