# Qt QWidget::minimumSizeHint delay (#2)

Tags: c++, qt

When i hide a widget in my application, the `minimumSizeHint` isn't updated immediatly.

I tried the `QLayout::activate()` solution suggested at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29439182/qt-qwidgetminimumsizehint-delay), but it doesn't work for me because  `QLayout::activate()` returns `false`.

I try to do it at `MainWindow` class like this:

```
ui.groupBox->setVisible(!ui.groupBox->isVisible());

qDebug() << this->layout()->activate();

qDebug() << this->minimumSizeHint();

this->resize(this->minimumSizeHint());
```

Any ideas why it's not working?

My current workaround is:

```
QTimer::singleShot(10, this, SLOT(on_resizeMin()));
```

but i noticed 10ms may not be enough on a slow system. Nasty workaround.

Comment: Does `invalidate` work?

Comment: you can use `adjustSize()` method, it not depends on `minimumSizeHint()`, but sometimes it have strange behaviour.

Comment: `invalidate()` does work in case of `activate()` returns `true` but `minimumSizeHint()` is still not updated. 
`adjustSize()` uses `sizeHint()` ([qt doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#adjustSize)) which isn't updated either and therefore has strange behaviour too.
So neither soves the problem :(

Answer (score 0):

The size hints are meant to be used at appropriate moments by the layout system. You're not supposed to be using them elsewhere - that's why they appear to "not work".

You appear to want to constrain the size of the main widget (the window) to one of the size hints. You'll need to set an appropriate `sizeConstraint`on that widget's layout. There are two approaches:

1. Use the `QLayout::SetFixedSize` constraint. Reimplement the layout's `sizeHint` to return `minimumSize`, such that the `QLayout::SetFixedSize` will set the window's size to the minimum size hint, not the default size hint.
2. Patch Qt to implement `QLayout::SetMinAndMaxToMinSize`, meaning "The main widget's minimum *and* maximum size are set to `minimumSize()`"

   The patch is small :)